# Space around html nodes

Tags: html, graphviz

How can I make the links connect the border of HTML nodes ?

```
graph {
  node[shape=plaintext];
  Object1[label=<<table><tr><td>Object1</td></tr></table>>];
  Object2[label=<<table><tr><td>Object2</td></tr></table>>];
  Link[shape="diamond", label="Link"];
  Object1 -- Link;
  Object2 -- Link;
}
```

Compilation : `dot -Tpng file.gv`

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukB4c.png) : Objects borders are a bit too far from the links extremities.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Why downvote? The question is cristal clear, the answer also, I couldn't make more concise. So tell me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an acceptable solution using references "port" inside TD cells:

```
graph {
  node[shape=plaintext];
  Object1[label=<<table border="0"><tr><td border="1" port="f1">Object1</td></tr></table>>];
  Object2[label=<<table border="0"><tr><td border="1" port="f2">Object2</td></tr></table>>];
  Link[shape="diamond", label="Link"];
  Object1:f1 -- Link;
  Object2:f2 -- Link;
}
```

(inspired by an example near the end of the doc page https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Qyh.png)

Comment: Note : it also work with "port" reference directly in <table> element